# Credit scorecard model

Tags: classifier

Could anyone point me to a blog or content that talks about creating credit scorecards without logistic regression models? Instead, if we use an ensemble technique, such as random forest, how can we create scorecards? Essentially, how do we create a scorecard model through a classifier which is difficult to interpret like random forest? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The point of scorecards is to build models that show nice properties (additivity of the score) and are easy to manipulate / understand. Using more complex models you will loose those properties. Are you sure that it is what you want ?

Comment: Also, can you be more precise what you mean by scorecards ? (because traditionnal scorecards are heavily linked to Weigths of Evidence that are in turn heavily linked to logistic regression)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I am trying to develop application scorecard for identified features for every applicant. So was exploring if WOE through logit is the only way to do or can we build around more advanced classifiers. For instance, even in random forest I get probability of default for every loan based on values of features. Can I extrapolate it to a score?

Comment: Generally speaking you can use complex models to build scores, a number that correlate with default probability. You can then often build something that can be considered as probability of default. However those models rarely fit into tables.

Comment: One alternative is to build a table based on default rate associated with some features, iteratively merge cells that exhibit similar default rates. This often can be represented as small trees. However this is rarely optimal and only works with small number of features / values.